# Getting different sequence of documents when upgraded from ES 1.4 to ES 2.3

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I used this query `curl localhost:9200/tweets/user/_search?size=25` on `es 1.4.2` and I got the following result:

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 6,
    "successful": 6,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 294633,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
...
```

with a list of documents.

When I ran the same query on `es 2.3.0`, I got same hits but the documents were completely different.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Shard setup and the content of each shard, thus different term frequencies and different relevance scoring?

Comment: I am using the default scoring as earlier. Running the query as above I get all the scores as `1`. I am not sure about the content of each shard

Comment: @AndreiStefan I just run `curl localhost:9200/tweets/user/_search?size=25`

Comment: Oh, so all the scores are equal. I bet that even if you reindex your documents in a separate index in the same 1.4.2 cluster (and if you have different IDs than the ones you already have) you will get different results. Anyway, the documentation says the order will be random: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_sorting.html#_sorting: "This will apply a constant score (default of 1) to all documents. It will perform the same as the above query, and all documents will be returned randomly like before, they’ll just have a score of one instead of zero."

Comment: Also, why does it matter to you the order of these documents (since it's random)?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I was about to apply custom scoring scripts on the documents but the simplest query gave random results so I got confused. Thanks for the link you mentioned.

Comment: I think you can safely apply that. The random ordering based on constant score for all documents will not affect your custom scoring script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says [the order will be random](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_sorting.html#_sorting):

> This will apply a constant score (default of 1) to all documents. It will perform the same as the above query, and all documents will be returned randomly like before, they’ll just have a score of one instead of zero.